# Wordpress DataBase Local Content different from Remote Content

Tags: wordpress, content, database

## Problem Description

I am developing a project using Wordpress as a CMS for a web page of a Scientific Research Group to Publish Information, News, Publications and Projects of the Scientific Group.

I began to develop the whole basic structure of the pages locally through the MAMP application and yesterday tried to migrate everything to my accommodation at GoDaddy.

## What I Did

Initially had some migration issues, I called them, they helped me in some way, but not all of all my problems.

It turns out that at the beginning I did the following:

1) Migrate all for Local Environment files for Remote for FileZilla FTP;

2) Set the file wp-config.php;

3) Export the Local Environmental Database by myPHPAdmin;

4) Import the Remote Environment Database through myPHPAdmin;

At the end of all this encounter that the contents of the Remote Environment is enrrado and I did the Technical GoDaddy do not know why.

## My Questions

a) Will there be any inconsistency with regard to versions used in place over the remote?

b) the use of plugins can cause this behavior?

c) Does the database should not be Exported in its entirety?

If case you happened the same please describe your situation and how to solve.

## Some Information

Here I will short describe some important information to understand my problem, with the main difference in Homepage between both environments.

### Remote Environment Test Link

[Test Webpage](http://nvwp.franciscocalisto.me/wordpress)

### Local Environment Screenshots

[image]

As you can observe the content is different as you watch.

Comment: Perhaps you could give some examples of how your production site is different to your local, this isn't obvious from the partial screenshot you included. Also, posting a full SQL dump of your database to a public forum is not a good idea, since this contains hashed passwords for your users.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to put here more then 2 links and images count as a link. So that I can not put here images with differences.

Thank you @Tim Fountain for your advices.

Comment: You don't have to use screenshots to describe the differences - textual description would help. Is the text on the production site different? The layout? Are images or pages missing? We are much less likely to spot minor differences when comparing your site visually to a screenshot than you are.

Comment: If you transfer files and db to another server, there will be no difference. I don't understand what you mean by 'enrrado and I did the Technical GoDaddy do not know why'. Anyway easiest thing to do create a wp installation at gd then overwrite with your files and db and update wp-config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you changed the URL in two places in the general settings in the dashboard?  If your new test site is actually pointing to the URL of the old site it can cause unexpected results.

If you can't change it in the dashboard - because this may prevent you loggin in - in the database in the wp_options table you will find two records with the URL.  Depending on which version you are using, they will either both be on the first page of records (in phpmyadmin) or one on the first page and the other on the second page.

Comment: Yes it was a URL configuration problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress stores `serialised data` for the links and other essential information about wordpress, what you've done wrong in my opinion is the export of the database.

I am using `WP Migrate DB` plugin to export database, and I've already used it for many websites without a problem, go over the process again and export your database with `WP Migrate DB` plugin and tell me if this works well for you.

Basically what the plugin does is to find and change urls in the database while exporting it and keeping the serialized data valid.